# Laravel Blade - Repopulate checkbox if validation failed?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

How do I repopulate the checkbox if validation form request failed but if user did not submit the form then use default value from the database?

Assume we have name input field and a checkbox.

Input Name

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="{{ old('name', $delivery->name) }}">
```

Checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="use_shipping"  @if(old('use_shipping', $delivery->use_shipping) == "1") checked="checked" @endif value="1">
```

The Input Name field is working correctly to repopulate the value via database or repopulate the value if validation request failed.

The checkbox does not repopulate if validation failed. How to fix this?

For example, if I did not enter the Name (Input Field) and I unchecked the `use_shipping` checkbox - it should repopulate checkbox after submitting a form (validation failed).

Comment: What's the extra double quote ( " ) after `value` attribute

Comment: @Michel Oop. I have edited the question. Problem still exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens, because browser does not append non-checked checkbox in the post data and thus value of `$delivery->use_shipping` is used when re-populating form.

You can add a hidden input with "default" value of `use_shipping` to fix this behavior:

```
<input type="hidden" name="use_shipping" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" name="use_shipping" value="1" {{ old('use_shipping', $delivery->use_shipping) ? 'checked="checked"' : '' }}>
```

This will work just fine when checkbox is checked, because latter values override former.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

`<input name="use_shipping" type="checkbox" value="1" {{ old('use_shipping', $delivery->use_shipping) ? 'checked' : '' }} />`

Comment: It same thing. It does not repopulate the checkbox if validation failed. It repoulating from database rather than `old` value if validation failed.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="use_shipping" @if(old('use_shipping') || (old('use_shipping', null) == null && $delivery->use_shipping)) checked @endif value="{{ old('use_shipping') || (old('use_shipping', null) == null && $delivery->use_shipping)) }}">
```

*Use shipping should be a boolean

Comment: I don't think this will work - `checked` doesn't accept a value. It's either present or not present.

Comment: This wont work. We need default checked or not checked via `$delivery->use_shipping` if form has not been submitted. If form has been submitted and validated failed it need to repopulate it via `old()`